# Play developer console "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later." when adding translations

Tags: android, firefox, google-play

I'm trying to add translations to my app and when finally after hard work of translating I click on `Save & Publish` and it says `publishing` for some minutes and then it doesn't publish but throws error in red container with message `An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.` Resubmitting doesn't help and I have to move away from the page and ALL TRANSLATIONS get lost, so it's about 30 minutes to 1 hour of time waste!

Anybody had similar issues? But the problem is that it doesn't occur always. I try to add only 3 translations and then it publishes, but then I add more, and it throws this error. Sometimes I add more translations and it works but then adding 3 additional it throws error. So I don't think it's about the quantity of translations. Also I have inspected with Firebug but don't see there any errors.
I have read other topics here that recommend logging out/in, clearing cache. I have done it, but it doesn't help. I had sometimes similar issue of unexpected error when looking at statistics in Play Developer Console but at the end the statistics part wasn't so important if it didn't work and I didn't invest my time there just to open it up, but for translations this is a real time consuming task and then in the end all this may get lost and have to paste translations `n` times until it will eventually submit!

**EDIT**
Alright, I found very strange workaround that always submit from first try.
So anyway open in Firebug ˇNetˇ tab and when pressing ˇpublishˇ you will see there a POST action is executed. Then it will just load and load and never finish. After about 2:58 minutes it gets aborted. So At this point right click on this POST request and click ˇResendˇ so it starts resending and right at the same time click on the button ˇPublishˇ. Yes the button is not grayed out. So within a second it posts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I found very strange workaround that always submit from first try.
So anyway open in Firebug `Net` tab and when pressing `Publish` you will see there a POST action is executed. Then it will just load and load and never finish. After about 2:58 minutes it gets aborted. So At this point right click on this POST request and click `Resend` so it starts resending and right at the same time click on the button `Publish`. Yes the button is not grayed out. So within a second it posts!

Answer (score 12):

If you are facing this issue in **july 2020** then the answer is that google has updated the play console and redirected on this url "https://play.google.com/console"
If you have not redirected automatically to the above link then manually open this link.

Answer (score 2):

Playstore have updated with new UI.

Please follow the link
[Updated Playstore Console Link from JULY 2020](https://play.google.com/console)

You can see new console

[image]